# why supervisor gunicorn shows fatal error command not found?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, gunicorn, supervisord

when i check status(sudo supervisorctl status) it is shwoing like this

```
guni:gunicorn                    FATAL     can't find command 
'/home/ubuntu/myvenv/js/bin/gunicorn'
```

and my gunicorn conf is like this

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory=/home/ubuntu/js/main_jntu
command=/home/ubuntu/myvenv/js/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/js/app.sock 
main_jntu.wsgi:application
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log
[group:guni]
programs:gunicorn
```

after this when i check status it shows an error like this

```
guni:gunicorn                    FATAL     can't find command 
'/home/ubuntu/myvenv/js/bin/gunicorn'
```

Comment: now im getting [fatal exited too quickly (process log may have details)]

Answer (score 9):

After installing gunicorn use below command

```
whereis gunicorn
```

It will give exact path where gunicorn located, then use that path in your gunicorn conf file.
Happy coding!!

Comment: now it is showing.     guni:gunicorn                    FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the issue is with the third line of your configuration file. The error message indicates that the `gunicorn` executable is not available in the `/home/ubuntu/myvenv/js/bin` directory. If you do `ls /home/ubuntu/myvenv/js/bin/gunicorn` you probably will get an error message.

I think you would need to check if you have correctly installed `gunicorn` in your virtual environment, using e.g. `pip install gunicorn`. Have a look at [this article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/14/how-to-deploy-to-digital-ocean.html); I think it would be helpful.